# Comparing two containers where order is insignificant

Tags: c++, boost, std, c++98

I store the parameter to a command as a string. I now wish to store multiple parameters in a container from the standard library or boost. The order of parameters is not significant.

For example for the command LIST, the following are equivalent:

```
LIST all verbose
LIST verbose all
```

I then wish to be able to compare two containers, where the comparison of `["all", "verbose"]` and `["verbose", "all"]` gives `true`.

What container would you recommend I use and how should I do the comparison?

Comment: Any sorted container.

Comment: @ForEveR Yes that would be a good way of doing it!

Comment: `std::unordered_set` is probebly the fastest solution.  Do you have C++11?

Answer (score 0):

`std::is_permutation(seq1_start, seq1_end, seq2_start)` will do what you want, w/o worrying about how they're stored. [ Available in C++11 or boost ]

However, that's potentially an `O(N^2)` operation.

If you don't want to pay that price during comparison, then you'll need an ordered container. Then you can (for example) use `std::equal(seq1_start, seq1_end, seq2_start)` to compare in linear time (`O(N)`).